# VisualStudio Team Services : How to deny access to a specific web page

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

My team uses  VSTS, both from Visual Studio and from the web UI.

I want to grant permissions so that access to the code source is restricted to members accessing from Visual Studio.

Specifically, I want to deny access to some members, to the **`Code`** menu (the `./_versionControl` controller) of the VSTS Web interface.

Does someone have suggestions or comments about how to do it?

Comment: This is a very strange request. What is your reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: I want to prevent code download from the web.
I know I can restrict access by IP, configuring Azure Active Directory to manage access to my Team Services accounts, but at the moment this is not my case. this could be a quick&dirty temporary alternative

Comment: But why? What's the difference between someone grabbing it from the web and someone grabbing it from Visual Studio?

Comment: No need for my team to access the code from the web. There are many situations, not necessarily fraudulent, in which is preferable not to expose the code to unnecessary risks. Suppose you are from a client and leave that page opened while you are at lunch ... 
If you have any proposal please help.

Comment: If you leave your computer unlocked you could probably just use Visual Studio or the command line to push the changes as well. Adherence to security rules is always going to be your biggest nightmare. You could add a branch policy or gated check-in build in place to catch some of these things.

Comment: yes @jessehouwing, when the access takes place from a corporate computer, you have means to restrict/catch wrong behavior.  
But how to discourage the practice to access to the project page from an unknown computer :-( ?

Comment: Training, awareness, constant vigilance and real understanding from your employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to assign people the Stakeholder license, that will automatically hide the code hub and all the code related API features.

There is no way to completely hide the code hub from users with basic license or MSDN license assigned. Plus, it wouldn't disable the REST API nor the older SOAP API.

What you're trying to accomplish will at the maximum lead to security by obscurity, no true solution.

Comment: Can be a solution, thank you (while it implies that one person must access the project with two different account, one for each role)